# Powershell ADSI problems

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm working on a GPO powershell script that is supposed to help us cut down on our logon time. What I need to do, is pull the current username, and then check if it is a member of a group. The code I have right now is

```
$strFilter = "objectCategory=user"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=OU;DC=DC;DC=DC")
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 100000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$colProplist = "samaccountname"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
$resultsarray = @() 
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
{
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties | where-object -property samaccountname -eq $env:username
    $objItem.samaccountname

}
```

Unfortunately, even though it prints the username, I can't figure out how to see which principal group it's a member of! Since this is running on client machines that don't have RSAT, I can't use the active directory cmdlets like `get-adprincipalgroupmembership`. Any help?

Comment: It's a standard LDAP property.  Just specify `$colProplist = "samaccountname","memberof"`.

Comment: Well, after a little bit of manipulating, that seems to do the trick. I feel a little bit silly, but I couldn't find much documentation on that part of it.

Comment: I've made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a standard LDAP property. Just specify `$colProplist = "samaccountname","memberof"`.

Don't feel silly about missing it.  The [MSDN AD LDAP doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is comprehensive, but not particularly usable, especially because it assumes you already understand class inheritance, and some properties have two different names and only one is ever valid and it sometimes seems to change depending on context.  Most people prefer alternate sources like [SelfADSI](http://www.selfadsi.org/user-attributes.htm).

Note that that is *not* a recursive search, but neither is `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`.  Getting a list of all AD groups a user is a member of directly or through group membership is exactly as painful as it sounds.  You get memberof for the user, then walk through every group and check it's memberof, and repeat that until you run out of parents, then return the unique list.  It's easier with the `ActiveDirectory` module, but it's not painless.

Comment: As far as I need to know, I don't need to check recursively past surface groups. I'm just taking those groups, feeding them into an array and checking them against a switch statement. It only needs a general understainding of whom it is executing for, and then it can do everything it needs to.